# Is there a jQuery map utility that doesn't automically flatten?

Tags: jquery, functional-programming

I'm mapping an array of two-tuples from one domain (dates) to another (timestamps). Unfortunately, it looks like `jQuery.map` auto-flattens the two-tuples I return, and I don't see a `do_not_flatten` parameter.

Am I missing something else in the library that won't auto-flatten?

**Addendum:** I assume that I shouldn't be using `Array.map`, which does not auto-flatten, because it is [JavaScript 1.6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). As I understand it, jQuery is supposed to abstract away the JavaScript version I'm running for compatibility reasons.

Comment: jQuery devs said that this is on purpose: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10541

Comment: Just opened a GH issue to bring this into the docs: https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/990

Answer (score 69):

I was having the same problem; it turns out you can just return a nested array from within the $.map callback and it won't flatten the outer array:

```
$.map([1, 2, 3], function(element, index) {
  return [ element + 1, element + 2 ];
});
=> [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

Whereas:

```
$.map([1, 2, 3], function(element, index) {
  return [ [ element + 1, element + 2 ] ];
});
=> [[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Really neat! But seriously, such a hack should't be needed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Real ugly, the map function should accept a boolean or something to control this behaviour.

Comment: I think the map function shouldn't flatten its result at all. I rarely have any reason to want this behavior. There should be a separate function for situations where someone wants the result to be flattened.

Comment: I wonder about the performance implications. But then again JS is quite fast usually

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what a "two-tuple" is and I'm not really sure I got it right from the Google results I looked at. But did you take a look at [jQuery.each](http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.each)?

Comment: A two-tuple is a pair of values (x, y). A three-tuple is a set of three values (x, y, z). Sure, I could do it using a loop, but the point of `map` is that you use a single function to map from an input type to an output type.

Comment: Maybe I'm out of my league, but "The translation function that is provided to this method is called for each item in the array" seems like a kind of a loop to me..

Comment: Could you maybe use arrays of objects, like [{a,b},{c,d},{e,f}] and have your callback function also return an object?

Comment: You're totally right -- map is equivalent to something like: `new_vals = []; for (old_val in old_vals) { new_vals.push(some_fun(old_val)) }`. Map is a cleaner way of expressing that: `new_vals = map(some_fun, old_vals);` I could use pair objects, like you suggest, but the plot library wants 2-tups.