# How to get name and name key from input that have array name

Tags: jquery

here is html inputs :

```
<input name="item[5689]" type="text" value="abcdefgh"></input>
<input name="item[6535]" type="text" value="abcd1"></input>
<input name="item[9856]" type="text" value="abcd"></input>
```

So need this type of array for post ajax call :

```
5689 => abcdefgh
6535 => abcd1
9856 => abcd
```

How it can be achieved by jquery ?

here I try but not success :

```js
$("input[name='item[^]']").each(function() {
  console.log("Name: " + this.name + ", index: " + $(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="item[5689]" type="text" value="abcdefgh"></input>
<input name="item[6535]" type="text" value="abcd1"></input>
<input name="item[9856]" type="text" value="abcd"></input>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate further on the expected result? You have what looks like a PHP associative array but how do you want that to look in JS? An object like `{"5689": "abcdegh", "6535": "abcd1", "9856": "abcd"}`?

Comment: I need to post data to php side so I need keys and values to store in DB

Comment: Could you please edit your question to show _exactly_ what format you need to send in the request?

Comment: Try put it in form and than try use serializeArray on form element https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_serializearray.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no attribute *matches expression* selector so your best option is to...

1. Find all the elements (by [attribute starts-with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/))
2. Filter them to make sure they match the expected format
3. Extract the input value and key from the name and [*map*](https://api.jquery.com/map/) them to [*entries*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)
4. Reduce that to the object result you want

```js
const rx = /^item\[(.+?)]$/

const result = Object.fromEntries(
  jQuery("input[name^='item[']")
    .filter((_, { name }) => rx.test(name))
    .map((_, { name, value }) => [[ name.match(rx)[1], value ]])
    .get())
    
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="item[5689]" type="text" value="abcdefgh">
<input name="item[6535]" type="text" value="abcd1">
<input name="item[9856]" type="text" value="abcd">
```

[jQuery's `.map()` appears to flatten the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703355/is-there-a-jquery-map-utility-that-doesnt-automically-flatten), hence the `[[...]]` which makes it suitable for `Object.fromEntries()`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler answer without `Regex`.

first find all the `inputs` with `name` that contains `[]`

via `[name*=]` notation. then iterate over the tags and take the substring

between `[` & `]` characters of the `name` and last get the value via

`.val()` method (not `index()` that will give you the `index` not the `value`)

```js
$("input[name*='item[']").each(function() {
  console.log("Name: " + this.name.substring(
    this.name.lastIndexOf("[") + 1, this.name.lastIndexOf("]")) + ", index: " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="item[5689]" type="text" value="abcdefgh"></input>
<input name="item[6535]" type="text" value="abcd1"></input>
<input name="item[9856]" type="text" value="abcd"></input>
```